# Speed of an Electric Elevator

Tags: forces, work, speed

Imagine I have an elevator that weighs one ton, and a 20 kilowatt electric motor is lifting it. I should get about 20000 newtons out of that motor, minus inefficiencies, which should accelerate the elevator upwards at ~10 m/s^2 until air resistance and friction become too great, at which point the elevator's speed stabilizes. I think I understand this part.

But what if my motor is only 5000 watts, trying to lift 1 ton? I have to use gears to reduce the motor speed before the elevator will move. Ignoring friction for now, how do I calculate the elevator's maximum speed? I know 1000 watts will be slower than 5000 watts (because it has to be geared lower), but *how much* slower?

Comment: There is no fixed relationship between motor power and output force... That's what gears are for...

Comment: How did you do the calculations the first time even?

Comment: JMac: I used this https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-calculate-the-electric-power-required-to-lift-100-kg-of-material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the 1 tonne is the mass of the elevator cargo...

If the elevator is rising at a constant $v$ metre/second, then the load is gaining potential energy, $PE$;$$PE=mgv=1000 \times 9.8 \times v=9800 v \text{  joules/second}$$

The load is gaining this energy from the energy put out each second by the motor, $P_{motor}$; so: $$9800 v=P_{motor}$$So just solve for the maximum speed possible for each power output

It is the responsibility of the system designer to include a gearbox that allows the motor to turn at maximum power while the elevator pulleys lift the load at the corresponding speed

Comment: Nice! I think I follow, but to confirm: Lifting 1 ton at 1 m/s in earth gravity requires a minimum of 9800 watts for the motor, without friction or inefficiency?

Comment: Yes... if the ton is really a tonne...